# how to insert data into primary key and foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql

I have three tables:

#### PATIENT DETAILS

```
ptID

firstName

lastName

address
```

#### IMPLANT DETAILS

```
impID

ptID

productID

productSerialNo
```

#### PRODUCT

```
productID

productName
```

---

I am inserting data in `PATIENT DETAILS` and `IMPLANT DETAILS` table on the same page from single button click .

I have a foreign key on the table `IMPLANT DETAILS (productID)` which I populate through the value on the dropdown list.

What my problem is how will I populate `foreign key (ptID)` in `IMPLANT DETAILS` table? When `ptID (PATIENT DETAIL)` will also be generated from the same button click at almost of the same time. How would I do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use entity framework for this. Please look this post [Inserting Objects](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/05/entity-framework-inserting-objects-with.html)

[Step By Step Example of Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/create-first-simple-EDM.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire two sql queries to do this.

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT_DETAILS (firstName,lastName,address) VALUES(NULL,'text');         
INSERT INTO IMPLANT_DETAILS(ptID,productID,productSerialNo) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),1,'text'); 
COMMIT;
```